What is the role of the low density in LDPC coding?
Why does the density of 1 in LDPC codes need to be low?
How do decoding algorithms take advantage of such low density? What about we applying the same LDPC iterative decoding to any other parity check matrix?
What happens if I increase the density?
Sorry if the question seems low effort but I did not find anything about this.

The computational effort increases with density to the point where the decoding takes far too long, rendering the code useless for most applications.

@DilipSarwate thank you, this makes sense. What about the code performance when increasing the density? I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162920/ldpc-behaviour-as-density-of-parity-check-matrix-increases that "According to Shannon's theorem, the reliability of the code should increase with the density of the parity check matrix. That is simply because more checks are made." however it seems somehow hand-waving. You could just give me some relevant references about the topic, that would be nice.


Why does the density of 1 in LDPC codes need to be low?

Because, otherwise it wouldn't be called LDPC. They'd just be binary block codes. There's MDPC, and HDPC codes as well; they get decoded differently (or decoded the same, but for a different purpose).

How do decoding algorithms take advantage of such low density?

Strange, you answer your question in the next question:

What about we applying the same LDPC iterative decoding to any other parity check matrix?

Sit down and look at a typical decoder for LDPC codes, any message passing decoder from your text book. Look how the number of messages exchanged per iteration is related to the number of 1s in each row or column.

What happens if I increase the density?

See above regarding complexity.
However, what really makes the difference to the error performance (assuming we just don't care about computational complexity) is that the Tanner graph of a dense matrix has a high chance of short cycles, and these lead to iterative decoders getting "caught" in self-amplifying errors with a bit of bad luck.

Sorry if the question seems low effort but I did not find anything about this.

They do seem like candidates for the first questions I'd expect to be asked during an oral exam on graph-based codes, so good on you for asking them to prepare for such a thing!
Regarding the low effort: well, it really boils down to looking at the algorithms yourself. I feel that once you do the decoding of something small (e.g. with 4 variable and 3 check nodes) yourself on paper, you'd immediately get a feeling for why higher-degree is computationally hard.
I don't know which literature you have access to, and where you are in your studies of iterative decoders and graph-based codes, but you should be learning that from the graph structure represented by the LD matrix arise code properties, like the aforementioned bad property of short cycles, and consequential things like error floors. If you are learning this on your own and don't have lecture material (and a lecturer you can ask), I'd recommend the book by W. E. Ryan and S. Lin, “Channel Codes: Classical and Modern”.

Thank you. I got it.
